# How do I understand "It doesn't work all the time"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, adverbs

1. It doesn't **work all the time**

That **doesn't** negates is **work all the time**, so it means: it works sometimes, but not always.

2. It **doesn't work** all the time

Adverbial **all the time** modifies **doesn't work**, it means: it doesn't work at any time.

which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always means the first: It means it works sometimes.  There is no real "logic" here, but the same pattern is true with other similar time expressions:

> It doesn't work every day = It works on some days.

Comment: The pattern has a little difference for this sentence: `It doesn't work any time`, here **any time** is as adverbial of **doesn't work**. So it may cause some ambiguity?

Comment: The combination  _not...any_ always has the sense _none, not at all_. It would be more idiomatic to say 'It doesn't work _at_ any time', but in either case the meaning would be 'It never works'.